# No data in the Test Plan Progress Report in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, scrum

I'm having some problems with the Test Plan Progress Report in TFS. It is not showing any data in there, even when i have several test cases and in different states, and also have assigned a Configuration  (Windows 7 and IE9) to each test case.  Do you know what else could be causing this annoying issue with the report?

The Test Case Readiness Report is working fine, but only this one is not working.

Comment: Ricardo, please see "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/)"

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem. After taking a lot of time in google or microsoft's website , there is still no answer be found. I decide to research the report design. It still take a lot of time since this is my first time to use SQL Server Report Builder.

I found the solution to this problem.

1. Open this report in report builder
2. go to DataSet > dsTestData
3. right click mouse > dataset properties
4. select field in left column
5. click 'fx' button of Passed_Cumulative_Count
6. change expression's variable  :
   change OutcomeCaption.Value="Passed" to Outcome_Id.Value="2"
7. change other fields as step 6
8. Outcome_Id :
   1  Other
   2 Passed
   3 Failed
   7 Blocked
   255 Never Run
9. Save your report
10. You should see test plan progress data now .
11. My TFS is in Traditional Chinese OS , the OutcomeCaption will be chinese word. This is why the orginal report has no data.

Hope this gives others some help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it turned out it was because I didn't have Test Plans defined.  Since I wasn't using a version of Visual Studio that had Microsoft Test Manager licensed, I wasn't able to define a Test Plan for my Test Cases.